# Use from json :how to recognize a json object as a string

Tags: java, json

I have a jsonobject which contain a jsonobject.

```
String Example1 = {name1:value;name2:{ name21:value, name22:value}}；
fromjson(Example1,some.class)；
```

I want to use `fromjson()` method to transfer Example1 into JAVA class. But I want to let `name2` be regarded as a String  not a `JsonObject`.
That is I want the value of `name2` become a string `{ name21:value, name22:value}`
What should I do?

Comment: so u want fromjson method work for any class right?

Comment: If you have control over generating the json object, convert it to produce something like **{"name1":"value", "name2":"{ \"name21\":\"value\", \"name22\":\"value\"}"}** to escape the second object. If not, I think you should wrote your own json parser.